# How do I modify a template file to show elements side-by-side?

Tags: views, 8, theming

I am working on views with embedded filters and my resultant view fields have the following code.

```
{ % set index = 0 %}
<div class='row'>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body">
      {% for key, field in fields %}

        {% if index == 0 or index == 5 %}
          <div class='col-md-6'>
        {% endif %}
        
        {% if field.wrapper_element %}
          <{{ field.wrapper_element }}{{ field.wrapper_attributes }}> 
        {% endif %}
         
        {% if field.label %}
          {% if field.label_element %}
            <{{ field.label_element }}{{ field.label_attributes }}>{{ field.label }}{{ field.label_suffix }}</{{ field.label_element }}>
          {% else %}
            {{ field.label }}{{ field.label_suffix }}
          {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
          
        <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="{{ tooltips[key] }}">

          {% if field.element_type %}
            <{{ field.element_type }}{{ field.element_attributes }}>{{ field.content }}</{{ field.element_type }}>
          {% else %}
            {{ field.content }}
          {% endif %}
         </a> 
        <br/>
        {% if index == 4 %}
          <br/>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="space"></div>
              <button class="button js-form-submit form-submit btn-info btn" type="button" value="Btn1" name="">Btn1</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <div class="space"></div>
              <button class="button js-form-submit form-submit btn-info btn" type="button" OnClick = "window.print();" value="PRINT" name="">PRINT</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        {% endif %}
  
        {% if field.wrapper_element %}
          </{{ field.wrapper_element }}>
        {% endif %}

        {% if index + 1 == fields | length %}
          <a href="">Click to go to next page</a>
        {% endif %}

        {% if index == 4 or index + 1 == fields | length  %}
          </div>
        {% endif %}

        {% set index = index + 1 %}

      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this setup the label is showing above the text. Is there a way to show them on the same line?

Comment: Instead of relying on Bootstrap markup have you tried it with your own CSS already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s likely because `field.label_element` contains a `<p>` tag.

You should instead use a `<span>` tag.

```html
<span {{ field.label_attributes }}>{{ field.label }}{{ field.label_suffix }}</span>
<a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="{{ tooltips[key] }}">
  <span {{ field.element_attributes }}>{{ field.content }}</span>
</a>
```

You can also add a `<br>` tag after the closing `<a>` tag to show all the label/content sets on separate lines.

If this doesn't work, you can add a `<div>` tag around the two elements and add some simple Flexbox styling in the CSS to get the desired result.